# Market Cap ranges for Tech Companies

Tags: value

I'm trying to get an idea of how big tech companies are based off market cap.  This is not my typical field of expertise, so please pardon me if I say something naive.

I've found this site (https://www.tradingview.com/screener/) in which I'm able to filter tickers by market cap and industry.  I tried looking through the list but didn't recognize anything in the lower areas.

---

I've also attempted to simply search for the market cap of tech companies I know of.  Heres' what I've got so far:

```
Cap   Company
----+------------
1T    Apple
950B  Alphabet
150B  Netflix 
29B   Ebay 
16B   Expedia
4B    TripAdvisor
2.5B  StitchFix
```

I couldn't find a single company under $1 Billion, thought I'm pretty certain it's possible.  Is there a minimum to this?  How can I find examples of tech companies at all ranges?  In general, how can I go about getting a grasp of size vs market cap in the tech field?

Comment: This would have been a more accurate Stack Exchange for me to ask on:  https://quant.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you find it mainly for large companies is that the market capitalization is by definition the market value of company’s equity.

If the company is not public it might not be possible to get the market value as for that you need to observe the price at which the company trades its equity (like shares on stock market for example). Most of the time only big companies go public because it involves a ton of extra regulatory requirements that small firm might not be able to even cope with.

Hence, small - medium size partnership or private limited companies do not generally sell equity publicly. The best you could do there would be some estimate based on some expert’s judgement of market valuation but I imagine that will be very hard to find and inherently very inaccurate. Sometimes even big company might decide to stay private to avoid greater regulatory burden but for bigger companies it’s usually easier to find some expert valuations or estimates of the firm value based on some other observable characteristics.